# Selecting elements which are created on the fly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a jQuery plugin listed [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) with something like:

```
$(document).(function($){
   $('input[id^="field-phone-"]').mask("0 (99) 999 9999");
});
```

It works fine normally. Yet, if I create another field run time, the selector does not select it. How can I make jQuery to be aware of that? I have seen the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) thing, but do not know how to implement it.

Comment: You can't. Not without ugly hacks as [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver). It is much simpler to just edit the code which adds those inputs to call the `mask` method as they are created and appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard jQuery the simple answer is that you can't. You'll need to call the `mask()` function again at the same time as creating your new elements.